# Compact subsets of infinite projective space

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let's define infinite projective space space $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ as direct limit $\lim \limits_{\rightarrow} \mathbb{CP}^n$. In a class I attended it was claimed that every continuous map $S^k \to \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ is actually valued in some subspace $\mathbb{CP}^N$ for some sufficiently high $N$. How to prove this?

Comment: A subspace of a CW-complex is compact iff it is closed and it intersects finitely many cells, see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2728666/compact-subset-of-cw-complex)

Comment: If $f_i: X_i \to X_{i+1}$ is a sequence of inclusions of compact Hausdorff spaces, then the direct limit topology on the union is such that any compact subset lies in one of the $X_i$. This is a nice exercise with the definitions.

Comment: @MikeMiller this is precisely what I expected, but I had some trouble with verifying this property. Could you prove some additional hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very general statement which is enough for your situation:

> Let $X_i \to X_{i+1}$ be a sequence of embeddings of $T_1$ spaces. Then any compact subset $K\subset \mathrm{colim}_i X_i$ is actually contained in an $X_i$.

A proof can be found here : [Compact subset in colimit of spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584667/compact-subset-in-colimit-of-spaces)

It's a very general statement, and the proof is not hard to follow.

Comment: As pointed out in a comment, my argument was false. I have deleted it.

Comment: @MikeMiller : thanks for pointing it out, I had not checked the argument, only the statement

Comment: Thank you! I hoped for something exactly of this type, but I expected much stronger assumptions to be necessary, e.g. each $X_i$ compact Hausdorff.